# admin-ajax.php returning 500 error in wordpress admin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use a Wordpress plugin called DNUI, which indexes and helps you delete unused images.

When I activate the plugin and click on it, the menus and buttons don't load.

Has anyone run into anything similar? Can you offer any guidance on fixing this? I tried various things like deactivating plugins but nothing's worked so far. I reached out to the developer of the plugin but he was too busy to look into the matter.

Thank you!

The console says:

```
 POST <my domain here>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 

m.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.extend.ajaxbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
b.ajaxbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
b.syncbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
c.extend.syncbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
c.extend.fetchdnui.js?ver=4.1.1:31 
Backbone.View.extend.dbdnui.js?ver=4.1.1:476 
dnuiMOption.fetch.data.successjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 
m.param.ejquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 Vcjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 
m.paramjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:4 m.extend.ajaxbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
b.ajaxbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 b.syncbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
c.extend.syncbackbone.min.js?ver=1.1.2:1 
c.extend.fetchdnui.js?ver=4.1.1:475 (anonymous function)jquery.js?ver=1.11.1:2 
m.Callbacks.jjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:2 
m.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:2 
m.extend.readyjquery.js?ver=1.11.1:2 J
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Having a similar issue with a different plugin and looking into ways to debug this.